# Rotate viewport

Tags: 3d-view, interface

zbrush have an option, which can rotate viewport when sculpting (not only x-y axis) and now i see a workflow on blender sculpt.
This option exist in blender, i tried many methods, but nothings, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the middle mouse button to orbit. To pan, hold shift + MMB. Alternatively, there are buttons you can press in the top right of your screen.

If you wish to switch to the front orthographic view, press 1 on Numpad. For side orthographic, press 3 on Numpad, and for top orthographic, press 7. If you want to view the opposite side, press 9.

There are many free beginner tutorials for Blender on Youtube that I would recommend you check out. You'll start to learn the dos and don'ts before you run into issues, and you'd probably find answers for your current/future problems much quicker that way.

[image: Movement gizmos]